# Damaged applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to run an applescript for 'phreeqc' ([see](http://wwwbrr.cr.usgs.gov/projects/GWC_coupled/phreeqc/README.Mac.TXT)) which was made for 10.4-10.8. When I try to open the script, it prompts that the file is damaged ([snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vWkZjZHp4T3MxTkk/edit?usp=sharing)) which is weird. Is that because my mac version is 10.9.1? Then how people run old scripts? Is there any alternative?

Comment: If you can post the file maybe someone can look at to determine what the issue is.

Comment: NO, I used it in a windows environment before, I'm just guessing what might have happened@summea. You (@l'L'l) can download it here: http://wwwbrr.cr.usgs.gov/projects/GWC_coupled/phreeqc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script runs fine on my system; I suspect OS X Gatekeeper is the culprit, since the bundle is not codesigned.

```
Open System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General 

1. Click the lock and enter your password
2. Tick Allow apps downloaded from Anywhere
```

Then try running the script again

Answer (score -2):

The same thing happened to me!

What you can do is to check your **Security & Privacy** and get info about the files and try to change them so you both can **Read and Write** in the.
Just rightclick and you will see **get info**.

Comment: Welcome. You can ask questions with your current reputation. What you cannot do at the moment is to post comments on other posts.